# Can I get an insurance refund if I cancel a Wizz Air flight just because I no longer want to go to the destination?

Tags: air-travel, insurance, cancellations, wizz-air

When I bought my ticket, I also bought the travel insurance option, which said that I can cancel my flight and get a refund. Now I've read that you only get the refund if you have a serious problem (like an accident or a severe illness) and I don't know if I am reading the right document.

The fact is that I want to cancel my flight just because I don't want to go anymore to that destination.

In this case can I get a refund or not?

Comment: Did you happen to book a flexible ticket?

Comment: Without a link, it's difficult to know but insurance typically rule out events that are completely under your control.

Comment: If I look at my bought services I can see something called WizzFlex. I am looking on the Internet to see what it means...

Comment: It seems that WizzFlex only lets me to make some changes to the flight, not cancel it. I guess I will have to fly now, in order not to lose my money.

Comment: The travel insurances are generally useless as there are tons and tons of rules around what would qualify as a legit claim. Most probably, they'd have something to block you from claiming this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Travel insurance covers you for non-voluntary causes, ie: accidents, illness, deaths, etc to yourself or immediate family members or travel companions.  It also covers acts by the airline or tour operators or other travel suppliers that may block or interrupt your travel plans.

But simply changing your mind is not covered. That is a choice you made and consequences of which are yours and yours alone to bare.